# Why does Lorca only have one Tribble?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, captain-lorca

In Star Trek Discovery [S1:E3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings) - *Context is for Kings*, we see Lorca's collection of extraordinary items, including a Tribble.

Now [the trouble with Tribbles](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tribbles_(episode)) is that they multiply.

My question is: **Why does Lorca only have one Tribble?**

Comment: Aside from your question, it would be a funny plot twist when Lorca realizes that the ultimate weapon against the Klingons was in his ready-room all the time.

Comment: "As far as I can tell, they're born pregnant" - McCoy.

Comment: I've removed most of the completely pointless links. They're not necessary.

Comment: As the responsible pet owner that he is, he neutered it :D

Comment: False premise. We have no idea how many he has. What is with all the utterly trivial questions?

Comment: Thanks @Edlothiad, re the links, on Stackoverflow they reward that behaviour because it pushes up the Google PageRank priority which helps the site and the community.

Comment: Hmm maybe we should care, I and other users here find it very tacky and really quite distracting

Comment: Unless you're asking how many Lora has, this question is a duplicate of the one you asked later: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/173666/1224

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How does he have only one?

We don't know for sure cause the show hasn't said (as of 11-7-17).   But to pull a [quote from TOS](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708480/quotes).

> Dr. McCoy: [enters after Kirk gets covered with tribbles] Jim! I think
>   I've got it. All we have to do is quit feeding them. We quit feeding
>   them, they stop breeding!
>
> Capt. Kirk: Now he tells me.

He either knows enough not to feed it (probably the explanation), or there's some less canonical explanation like it's a male (are there males?), it's fixed, or it's stunned or dead.

I like the not feeding it option best and I hope they go with that.

Comment: I have always thought that Lorca was an animal person, so he will not allow the tribble to starve. He has even fed the tardigrade with his Chief of Security :) )(indirectly)

Comment: @EdmundDantes that got dark really quickly

Comment: Tribbles are hermaphroditic and capable of asexual reproduction via self-insemination, resulting in offspring that are born pregnant. If it is fed even the smallest amount, it reproduces exponentially. If Captain Lorca has only one Tribble, it _must_ be because he's not feeding it, otherwise..... he'd have a whole lot more than one Tribble.

Comment: In some scenes, you can hear Lorca's tribble purring, so it's not stunned or dead.